# Display readmore link in all blog entrys

Tags: articles, content, category

I am trying to get a readmore link after every single blog entry on a Joomla 3.2.3 Page.

I already edited `components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_item.php` to take out the php `if ($params->get('show_readmore')`.

But entrys with just little Text are still missing a read more link.
The position of the read more link seems to be set by a fixed number of characters to limit the blog-text length - which is an option I have not found (yet?).

Comment: Hope you did a template override for this. The part you deleted was the check for the switch to display the read more-text. You could have achieved this in the admin backend with turning on 'Show "Read more"' in the Options part of the menu item. This way it is a little easier and update safe.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.
There is another file controling the frontpage blog.

After deleting `if ($params->get('show_readmore')` in `components/com_content/views/featured/tmpl/default_item.php` too I got the result I hoped for.

Comment: I hope you are aware that editing this file is not update safe, so perhaps you created a template override instead...